# OpenPGP 2.x Smartcard Lifetime?

Tags: smartcard, openpgp

What's the average lifetime of using an OpenPGP 2.x Smartcard with an USB Reader (Gemalto K30)?

And does the USB (SIM) reader has a significant influence on the smartcards lifetime? (Because the chip is permanently plugged in the USB reader - and therefor minimizing the physical "damage" done by sliding the card in/out the reader.)

Comment: What is the manufacture of the card guidance?

Comment: Its the G10 from Germany. I havent found any.

Answer (score 0):

I have used smartcards/PIV/CACs for the last 8 years. By life, if you mean physically, it will depend on environment variables such as where it is stored, how it is stored, how often it is used. 
I have had some cards only last a few months and and i have had one last almost 4 years. One card, the chip just came out of the card. My card that lasted almost 4 years was kept in a plastic sleeve. My other card where kept in my leather wallet which wore down onto the chip, not to mention got sat on.

If you have it just in there and never take it out, it is far to say it should last the life of the certificate.